# Providing Only the Path from an Assembly File

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, build

Here is my question; currently I'm using a certificate key file that is located locally on my computer that is required to send a webrequest. This project will be used amongst others and I'm not comfortable sending my certificate to them.

I'm attempting to have the file included in the project on build, using Build Action - Content. Though, I am unable to find the location of this file. I have also used "Embedded Resource" as a Build Action but I ran into issues because I am only able to load the file in a stream, which isn't what I'm looking for because the object:

```
 X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certName, password);
```

Only uses the location of the certificate file and does not require it to be opened.

Could anyone please provide a solution where I am able to build the file into the project and only reference its path to the object above?

Thanks,

Comment: So you want to hide a client certificate from the end users of your application?  You can make it marginally difficult but there is no bullet proof method.  If you want to keep it to yourself make your client app call a webservice you create that then calls the real web service with the certificate - that way they don't need it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the certificate as follows, by providing the embedded resourceName:

```
using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
        {
            Byte[] assemblyData = new Byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
            var cert = new X509Certificate2();
            cert.Import(assemblyData);
        }
```

But as @Alex.K said in the comment it will only marginally increase security as 'Resources' is very easily accessible, the only thing you will achieve will be that the file will not be readily visible.

Comment: That did it! Thank you. Yes I understand, since this will be used internally, I'm hoping removing the visibility as much as possible will help.